# Class 'S3Client' not found from within object method

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application on AWS EC2 stores image-files on AWS S3. I am using the following AWS code snippet to create a Guzzle client to the S3 API:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client; // Namespace alias.
...
$s3_gClient = S3Client::factory(array(
   ...
   ));
```

This works fine - but is repeated at several places in the application.
Now, I'd like to use a method to be called from all these places instead.
I tried this:

```
  $s3ClientNamespaceString = "S3Client";
  $sg->prepare_aws_s3_guzzle_client($s3ClientNamespaceString);
```

with the method defined as:

```
  public function prepare_aws_s3_guzzle_client($s3ClientNamespaceString) {
    $s3_gClient = $s3ClientNamespaceString::factory(array(
       ...
       ));
    }
```

This is not working - I get a PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'S3Client' not found
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying - i.e. to use a namespace alias within a method ?

Comment: Not having worked on the AWS SDK before, shouldn't `$s3ClientNamespaceString = "S3Client";` be `$s3ClientNamespaceString = "Aws\S3\S3Client";`? Namespaces are per file, not global across whatever is included beyond that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am experimenting with your suggestion. I'm not clear with namespaces yet - but I wonder why AWS would insist on using such approach if it sums up to a mere shorthand notation.